# "No Isolation Shared" Databricks job cluster through CLI

Tags: databricks, databricks-unity-catalog, databricks-cli, databricks-workflows

I turned on Unity Catalog for our workspace. Now a job cluster has an access mode setting. ([docs](https://docs.databricks.com/data-governance/unity-catalog/compute.html#access-mode)) I can manually change this setting on the UI:

[image]

But how do I control this setting when creating the job through `databricks jobs create --json-file X.json`?

Comment: The worst part is, even if I set it manually, running `databricks jobs reset --json-file` resets the access mode to single user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the `data_security_mode` with value `"NONE"` in the cluster definition (for some reason it's missing from API docs, but you can find details in the [Terraform provider docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/resources/cluster#data_security_mode)).  But really it should be the default value, so you don't need to explicitly specify it.

Comment: The docs refer to SINGLE_USER, USER_ISOLATION, LEGACY_PASSTHROUGH and LEGACY_TABLE_ACL. How are those mapped to the options in the UI? Unfortunately I can not find much on that in the documentation, maybe you could point me to some more information on that

Comment: Look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/compute#--what-is-cluster-access-mode - first two are for UC, and last two - without UC

Comment: So USER_ISOLATION = Shared in the UI? I am unfortunately not able to follow you:(

Comment: Gist of my question would be, how does the security mode map to the cluster access mode, how are those concepts related / mapped?

Comment: `USER_ISOLATION` - Shared for UC, `LEGACY_PASSTHROUGH` - former Credential Passthrough cluster, `LEGACY_TABLE_ACL` - with Table Access Control instead of UC. `NONE` - Shared, No User isolation

Comment: Wonderful, thanks! It works! But if I don't specify it, I really get "Single user" by default. Maybe it's a difference between the Terraform provider and the CLI.

Comment: I think that’s different behavior for UC non-UC. The docs publish for UC is still in progress